# Swift: Custom Nav Bar Image not firing action on click

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar on my viewcontroller.

I have created a custom image (of a cog) and have got that to show right:

```
//Add bar item
var image = UIImage(named: "settingsIcon")
image = image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)

NavigationBar.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: "addTapped")
```

I added the action to the above code:

```
action: "addTapped"
```

Then I created a function:

```
func addTapped() {
    print("Tapped")
}
```

When I run the app, the image shows fine. When I click the image nothing happens, not even an error.

Am I doing something blatantly wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `target` to `self` instead of `nil`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Pfffft. Time for  break I think. Thanks man :)